# Build string to be used externally in while loop

Tags: php, mysql, function, mysqli

i am looking to build a string while inside a mysqli while loop. i have a pages table that contains all the pages for my webapp however it has come to seo friendly these urls

my table looks like this

```
ID | Page Slug | Parent
------------------------    
1  | Accounts  | 0
2  | Customers | 1
3  | Details   | 2
```

say i call the below function WebApp_UOC_Construct_Url(3) with the page id 3 it will echo out a url with one that looks like the below

```
/accounts/customers/details
```

this url is how i want it to be passed to my menus so i know the function is working however this will only echo on the page i need it to return a value inside the href and so if i change the echo to return and call the function like this

```
<a hef='" . WebApp_UOC_Construct_Url(3) . "'>Customer Details</a>
```

i only receive the last entry in the database so the url will look like this

```
/details
```

what other possible methods are there of creating the above

```
function WebApp_UOC_Construct_Url($page_id)
{
    global $webapp_db;

    $get_URI = mysqli_query($webapp_db,
               "SELECT * FROM wa_sys_navigation WHERE wa_nav_id = '" . $page_id . "' ");

    while($found_URI = mysqli_fetch_array($get_URI))
    {
        WebApp_UOC_Construct_Url($found_URI['wa_nav_parent']);
        echo "/" . $found_URI['wa_nav_slug'];
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you print your SQL query before running it: `"SELECT * FROM wa_sys_navigation WHERE wa_nav_id = '" . $page_id . "' "`? So, we knew, what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change only `echo` to `return` you will get only the top level function call result. You need summarize the recursive calls results.

Example:

```
$parent = WebApp_UOC_Construct_Url($found_URI['wa_nav_parent']);
return $parnet . "/" . $found_URI['wa_nav_slug'];
```